# Does an ingress talk to pods directly or its through a service?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I came to know that Nginx Ingress talks directly to pods NOT through a service.

[Why endpoints and not services](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#why-endpoints-and-not-services)

> The NGINX ingress controller does not use Services to route traffic to the pods. Instead it uses the Endpoints API in order to bypass kube-proxy to allow NGINX features like session affinity and custom load balancing algorithms.

Is this specific to this type of ingress or the idea is applicable to all ingresses?

Answer (score 0):

The same is true for HAProxy as Ingress Controller

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).